# match letters but not digits nor spaces with regex

Tags: regex

Fro text in the format, "digit names" like:

```
"12232 letter" but not this one: "12232 12"
```

This expression works fine for both:

```
\d{3,}\s+\D'
```

But is there is any additional space it stops working:

```
re.search('\d{3,}\s+\D','12232   1111').group()
```

If returns:

```
'12232   '
```

as a match.

Comment: It looks quite clear to me. `\D` just matches the second space after 3 or more digits, and calls it a day.

Answer (score 2):

Though your question is rather unclear, from the title you probably want to use a set containing ranges of letters `[a-zA-Z]+`

```
>>> re.search(r"[a-zA-Z]+", "12232 letter").group()
'letter'
```

.. or try grouping explicitly with `()` and then getting the number of the group

```
>>> re.search(r"(\d{3,})\s+\D",'12232   1111').group(1)
'12232'
```

Else you could use `.findall`, which will return every run found

```
>>> re.findall(r"\d+", '12232   1111')
['12232', '1111']
```

Finally, the site https://regex101.com is great for helping to construct, test, and share regexes.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `\D` also matches all the chars that are matched with `\s`. You need to subtract `\s` pattern from `\D`. It can be easily achieved by converting the `\D` into its negated character class equivalent `[^\d]` and adding `\s` into it: `[^\d\s]`.

Use

```
m = re.search('\d{3,}\s+[^\d\s]','12232   1111')
if m:
    print(m.group())
else:
    print("No match!")
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/oCptVy).

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is unclear. 
I am guessing the requirement is:

- A number three or more digits long
- Followed by one or more spaces
- Followed by a word consisting of one or more letters only

\d{3,}\s*[A-Za-z]+